# Ho do i get both belongsTo() and hasMany() relations with a result?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model like this.

```
  namespace App\Models;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Item extends Model
  {

      public function brand()
      {
          return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
      }
      public function banner()
      {
          return $this->hasMany(Banner::class);
      }
  }
```

So if i want to get Item with brands i'm doing `$items = Item::with('brand')->get();`
But now i need to get Item with both brand and banner, how should i do that?

I've tr`Item::with('brand', 'banner')->get()` but banners are empty this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass all the relationships you want to load into `with()` as an array:

```
$items = Item::with(['brand', 'banner'])->get();
```

> Sometimes you may need to eager load several different relationships in a single operation. To do so, just pass additional arguments to the `with` method

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

You can conectate the with method like so

```
$items = Item::with('brand')->with('banner')->get();
```

Or in one array (like Alexey Mezenin wrote)

```
$items = Item::with(['brand', 'banner'])->get();
```